# Program with FastReport using MyDACDatabase doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport, mydac

I'm using the MyDACDatabase components to connect my report build with FastReport 4 to my MySQL database. I can edit it normally and test in the FastReport designer when using my Delphi's IDE, even compile the application, but when I open the form that have the report, I have the exception **Class not found: TFrxMyDACDatabase not found**. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is the unit where this class resides in your unit uses list?

Comment: Hi @jachguate! Well, your question make me somehow, to find the answer for my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone else wondering, the same problem happened to me all I did was, was changed the Library path to include the location of FR5 and added frxmyDACComponents to the uses list again.

Answer (score 0):

You should install FastReport X MyDAC Components from MyDAC 5 to be able to use the TfrxMYDACDatabase component. For more information please read the ReadMe.txt file in the %MyDAC%\Demos\Win32\ThirdParty\FastReport\FRX\ directory. %MyDAC% is the MyDAC installation path on your computer, X is the version of the Fast Report components that you use.

(Quoting from [Something change in version 5 for tfrxMyDacDatabase (Version 4 no problem)](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=9650))

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. I realised that in the **FastReport 4**'s tab I have a component named **frxMyDACComponents** in the pallete that I installed following the instructions in the MyDAC's Demos folder (in my case, placed into **C:\Users\Public\Documents\Devart\MyDAC for Delphi 7\Demos\ThirdParty\FastReport\FR4\ReadMe.txt**). When I placed this component in my form, 2 units were declared in the uses clause: **frxDACComponents** and **frxMYDACComponents**. Just that was needed to this problem. Thanks for the help of everyone.